# How to merge dataframes with different column names without dropping any rows/observations?

Tags: r

I have two dataframes which only slightly differ in column names:
Call the first one df1:

```
ID   azC   deC   PdC
101  2     3      2
102  3     1      1
103  0     1      2
104  0     3      0
```

Call the second df2:

```
ID   azP  deP    PdP
203   3   2      1
204   2   2      3
266   0   3      0
277   3   3      1
```

So, ID is the same in both dataframes. The column names only differ by the ending. df1 has C at the end and df2 has P. The names are the same otherwise.

When I try this method:

```
df_all <- merge(df1, df2, by=c('ID'))
```

I get dropped values. I want to retain all the values such that the data endings of P come after the endings of C:

```
ID  azC   deC   PdC   azP   deP  azP
```

Is there a way to do this in R? Or is it easier to do it with completely raw data before organizing it in a df?

Comment: you need `merge(df1, df2, all =TRUE)`

Comment: Seems to work better but it is missing some values also.